# In an SPA, should I validate data sent from the backend?

Tags: validation, architecture

I have a react-based single page application.

If the wrong data got sent from the back-end, it could potentially crash the front-end application. Naturally, this shouldn't happen, but it's a possibility.

Should data received from the back-end be validated before adding it to the data layer in the react app?

Comment: Is the backend 1st party or 3rd party?

Comment: It's our backend

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't. The backend's responsibility is to provide an API which clearly articulates what should consumer expect under what circumstances.

Comment: Frontend should handle these documented cases and all unknown errors as the UI/UX design dictates.

Comment: Thanks v much Peter.

Comment: shall I leave an answer with a more detailed reasoning?

Comment: Sure, go ahead if it gets you some bonus points. For me, the question was about defensive programming, but you're right that it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

#### The contract

First and foremost there must be a **contract** between backend and frontend. It can be obligatory and created upfront like in case of gRPC. Or in case of REST it can be auto-generated from the backend code via tools like OpenAPI.

Here both parties **agree** what should be the expected response if the client calls a given endpoint. And it should cover not just the happy path. Any valid outcome should be included in the contract.

#### Known vs unknown

The contract itself can **NOT** cover all the possible outcomes. There are situations which can not be foreseen. These unknowns should tackled as gracefully as possible on the client-side to make a great user experience under suboptimal circumstances as well. UI/UX design should exist also for these cases.